# Make custom dropdown also collapse when clicking the expander?

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

didn't know how to name this thread:

I build my own little dropdown.

```
$('.select .option').live('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
        $(".select .option:not('.darr')").hide();
        selectedOption = $(this).parents("div.select").find(".option:first");

        $(this).siblings().show();
        selectedOption.text($(this).text()).attr("title",this.title);
});

$('.select .option:not(".darr")').live('click', function () {
    $(this).parents("div.select").find(".option:not('.darr')").hide();
    console.log($(this).attr('data-ajax-link')); 
});

$(window).click(function() {
    $(".select .option:not('.darr')").hide();
});
```

Here is a working live sample. http://jsfiddle.net/K8VtB/4/

It works just fine. It collapses when clicking anywhere else on the page and when clicking onto another dropdown. However how can I make it also collapse when clicking again onto the first child that initially expanded the dropdown.

Right now when I expand it and click again onto the first element it doesn't collapse again. Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.toggle()`.  I adjusted your code to simplify.  The first click handler is for the `.darr` option.  It hides all the selects except itself, and then toggles its options.

The second click handler is for the options.  It only set's the text of `.darr` and lets the click event propagate to the window for closing the selects.

I didn't touch the window click handler.

http://jsfiddle.net/K8VtB/12/

```
$('.select .option.darr').live('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".select").not($(this).closest(".select")).find(".option:not(.darr)").hide();
    $(this).siblings().toggle();
});

$('.select .option:not(".darr")').live('click', function () {
    $(this).siblings(".darr").text($(this).text()).attr("title",this.title);
});

$(window).click(function() {
    $(".select .option:not('.darr')").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `toggle`:

```
$('.select .option').live('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // slight optimization, cache the selector for subsequent use
    var $parentDiv = $(this).closest("div.select");  

    // hide other expanders
    $parentDiv.siblings().find(".option:not('.darr')").hide();

    // toggle current expander
    $parentDiv.find(".option:not('.darr')").toggle();

    selectedOption = $parentDiv.find(".option:first");
    selectedOption.text($(this).text()).attr("title",this.title);
});
```

I also used `closest("div.select")` to isolate toggling to current `ul` only.

Here's a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mrchief/K8VtB/11/

**Update**: I missed the part where clicking on other expander hides the previous one. Update my code and fiddle for that.

Comment: This won't close all the dropdowns on the page, just the ones that are siblings.

Comment: That wasn't in the fiddle that OP provided.